# How to to run jQuery Mobile on locale maschiene with file:-protocol in Safari

Tags: jquery-mobile, safari, locale

I need to run jQuery Mobile locale in Safari with file:/// protocol in kiosk mode. The problem is that Safari throws the

> 'error loading page'

error when using file:/// protocol.

Is there a way to run jQuery Mobile in Safari locale?
Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to disable AJAX page linking

```
<a href="file:///anotherPage.html" data-ajax="false">Another Page</a>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

A different approach might be to go with a Single Page App design? All "pages" are loaded into the same single physical HTML document. Multiple DIVs with `data-role="page"`.

Comment: ok, seems that I loose all the JS objects and script references when I load the pages with data-ajax="false". looks like I need to create a really big HTML construct.

Comment: jquery mobile with ajax loading maintains the DOM so it makes sense that your java script is maintained. With it turned off, new page requests re-load the DOM. Guessing you can still maintain state across pages but honestly, you are getting a bit beyond my area of expertise. I am not very strong with javascript.

Comment: I think putting all in one file is the best workaround then. not the finest art of programming but at least I think it will work. thanx!